# JButton not showing properly: Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jbutton

[Javs Swing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1G3T.jpg)
You can see the code and output in above image. I have used Eclipse IDE for Java swing. But the button is not coming as expected. I'm new both to Java Swing and Eclipse so I don't know if any additional settings is requiered. Please help me and Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no image!, you have to write your code instead of using image. please explain the error

Comment: 1. It is hard to help you when "as expected" is not defined. 2. Please post code and not images of it. 3. Do not use null layout. Instead use the appropriate [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do not post images of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be the layout manager of your panel, **(if you are not using panel , you should use panel to add objects not frames directly)**  , if you use a layout manager , it follows some rules to position objects in the panel. like to keep the layout Manager to be null , although idk y people don't like when you say layout manager to be null but if you want to work with absolute positions , setLayout(null); could work

Answer (score 1):

You wrote in your question

> I'm new ... to Java Swing

Then I recommend that you go through the tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

Do not call method `setBounds()` to place your components – unless you are not using a layout manager<sup>1</sup> but according to your code, you are using a layout manager, since your code does **not** call `frame.setLayout(null)`.

The default layout manager for [the content pane of] `JFrame` is [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). Since your code does not use the [add(Component, Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-) method to add the `JButton` and `JTextField` to the `JFrame`, both components are added to the CENTER panel and hence are drawn one on top of the other. Also the CENTER panel makes its components as big as possible. Hence the `JButton` takes up all of the `JFrame`.

Here is a rewrite of your code, but I really recommend that you take the time and make the effort to go through the entire tutorial – if you are serious about learning *Swing*. Also note that in the below code I changed those names that do not adhere to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). We use naming conventions so as to make it easier for us to read other people's code and for other people to read our code.

Other things to note in the below code.

- The `ActionListener` implementation uses a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)
- All *Swing* code must execute on the *Event Dispatch Thread* (EDT). When you create and display a `JFrame`, it also starts up the EDT, however you can also write code that explicitly starts up the EDT and that is what I have done in the `main()` method in the below code.
- You can call one of the `setLocation...()` methods to place your `JFrame` in a particular part of the screen. If you don't, then it is placed in the top, left corner of the screen. The below code calls `setLocationByPlatform()` to let the host operating system decide where to locate the `JFrame` on the screen.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JavaSwingPractice implements Runnable {

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dialog Box!");
        JTextField textF = new JTextField(14);
        JButton button = new JButton("Click!");
        button.addActionListener(e -> textF.setText("Success!"));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(textF, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new JavaSwingPractice());
    }
}
```

Yes, in the above code I do not call `setDefaultCloseOperation()` because, at least in JDK 8, the default appears to be `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

<sup>1 – Refer to the Swing tutorial for explanation and details regarding layout managers.</sup>